# Upsert list with values of another list

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have 2 lists, they show the ForecastingQuota of my users for Quarter 1 and Quarter 2. I want to copy all the values of Quarter 1 to Quarter 2 if I choose the quarter on the SelectList (just copy the quota Amount of the user). How can I achieve this?

```
<apex:outputText>Copy Quarter</apex:outputText>
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedQuarterToCopy}"  size="1">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!QuarterList}" />
</apex:selectList>
<apex:outputText>To this Quarter</apex:outputText>
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedQuarterCopied}"  size="1">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!QuarterList}" />
</apex:selectList>

<apex:commandButton value="Copy Quarter to Quarter" action="{!copyQuarterToQuarter}" styleClass="buttonCopyQuota" reRender="null" />

List<ForecastingQuota> queryQuotaListQ1 = [SELECT Id, QuotaAmount, QuotaOwnerId, QuotaOwner.UserRole.Name, StartDate FROM ForecastingQuota WHERE ForecastingTypeId = :forecastTypeList.get(0).Id AND StartDate >=:selectedQuarterQ1 AND StartDate <:selectedQuarterQ2 AND QuotaOwnerId IN : userIdSet ORDER BY QuotaOwnerId ASC];
List<ForecastingQuota> queryQuotaListQ2 = [SELECT Id, QuotaAmount, QuotaOwnerId, QuotaOwner.UserRole.Name, StartDate FROM ForecastingQuota WHERE ForecastingTypeId = :forecastTypeList.get(0).Id AND StartDate >=:selectedQuarterQ2 AND StartDate <:selectedQuarterQ3 AND QuotaOwnerId IN : userIdSet ORDER BY QuotaOwnerId ASC];
```

[image: example]

Comment: I don't understand your question. Cant' you just make a queryQuotaListQ2.addAll(queryQuotaListQ1)?

Comment: I have update my post with a picture. In the first column I get the Quota for Quarter 1 2017, in the next column I have Quota for Q2 2017. And with the picklist and button in yellow, here I want to choose and copy the values of Selected Quarter (Quota Amount for each users) in an other Quarter, like duplicate values for different Quarter. Thx

Comment: How about you clone th list and then iterate through the newly copied list and change the values to th new quarter?

Answer (score 0):

I second the idea of cloning and looping through.  So basically you would do something like

```
 // get start date of next quarter
startOfQuarter = [Select startDAte From Period Where type = 'Quarter' and StartDate = THIS_FISCAL_QUARTER].startdate; 
startofQuarter = startOfQuarter + 100; 
startOfQuarter = startOfQuarter.toStartOfMonth();

List<ForecastingQuota> queryQuotaListQ1 = [SELECT Id, QuotaAmount, QuotaOwnerId, QuotaOwner.UserRole.Name, StartDate FROM ForecastingQuota WHERE ForecastingTypeId = :forecastTypeList.get(0).Id AND StartDate >=:selectedQuarterQ1 AND StartDate <:selectedQuarterQ2 AND QuotaOwnerId IN : userIdSet ORDER BY QuotaOwnerId ASC];
List<ForecastingQuota> queryQuotaListQ2 = new List<ForecastingQuota> queryQuotaListQ2();
for(ForecastingQuota forecast: queryQuotaListQ1) {
    ForecastingQuota newForecast = forecast.clone(false, false, false, false);
    newForecast.startDate = startOfQuarter;
    queryQuotaListQ2.add(newForecast);

}
insert queryQuotaListQ2
```

;